# Viewing changes to deleted files in git

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Let's say that when I branch off from master, there's a file `colors.txt` on the `master` branch of my repo with these contents:

```
red
green
blue
yellow
```

I then branch off into `my-branch`, in which I make the following changes:

1. Delete `colors.txt`
2. Add `red.txt` with these contents:

   ```
   red
   ```
3. Add `green.txt` with these contents:

   ```
   green
   ```
4. Add `blue.txt` with these contents:

   ```
   blue
   ```
5. Add `yellow.txt` with these contents:

   ```
   yellow
   ```

Now, there have been some changes on master that I need, so I want to merge. However, someone has also changed `colors.txt` to:

```
red
green
blue
yellow
orange
purple
```

During my merge, the only information I get is that I deleted the file `colors.txt`, so how can I see the changes that have been to the file on master so I can appropriately resolve the conflict (in this case, by adding the files `orange.txt` and `purple.txt`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can show all changes done to that file on master using this command:

```
git diff HEAD...master -- colors.txt
```

This should lead to this output in your case:

```
red
green
blue
yellow
+orange
+purple
```

Using three dots for `git diff` will show the changes of all commits which are parents of the second referenced commit but not of the first referenced commit. Therefore, using this you will see all changes which would be merged if the file had not been deleted.

By using `-- colors.txt` the changes shown by `git diff` are limited to that file.

A more generic version of that command would be

```
git diff HEAD...MERGE_HEAD -- colors.txt
```

`MERGE_HEAD` is always set to the merged commit, thus it can replace the merged branch name. Using this you could even set up an alias to reuse this command:

```
git config --global alias.merge-diff-theirs "diff HEAD...MERGE_HEAD"
```

Afterwards you can just do

```
git merge-diff-theirs -- colors.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer both did exactly what I needed and was incredibly simple. A quick note, however, I was able to get the same results as `git diff HEAD...MERGE_HEAD -- colors.txt` with `git diff HEAD...MERGE_HEAD colors.txt`.

Comment: `--` is used to separate revisions/arguments from paths. In cases where git detects that an argument is not a revision but a valid path to a file, it will assume the dashes. However if you had e.g. a branch named colors.txt that would fail.

Comment: Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky scenario, right? I think the best you can try to do is find out "when" color.txt was deleted. If you weren't merging, I'd say: use a bisect to find out when the file disappeared so you can see what happened but you are merging so that's no good. `git blame --reverse` can help *somewhat* by telling you when was the last time the file was **present** on your working tree. `git log --name-status -- <file-path>` can also help you see when the file disappeared (and why, through a nicely written revision comment, right?). I would tell you to give difflame a testdrive (A tool I worked on that by blending blame and diff output would be able to tell you the exact revision where the lines were deleted) but I think that because the file was **deleted** altogether, it will break.. not sure though. Here's the link just in case: https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame. Now... if you are able to find out on which revision the file was deleted, you might find out *why* it was deleted and you should figure out that you have to create a file for the new color that was added to color.txt *while* keeping color.txt deleted so that the merge is "complete".

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tested the following:

- Checkout a new branch *color-test*
- Add orange/purple to existing *colors.txt* and commit
- Switch back to "master"
- Delete *colors.txt*
- Try merge, which fails

For me, `git diff colors-test.. -- colors.txt` gives the following output:

```
-red
-green
-blue
-yellow
-orange
-purple
```

where `color-test` is the branch where I added orange/purple and `..(nothing)` indicates the `HEAD`. This might be okay when the file is that small, however, a full diff might be better.

To find out, in which commit you deleted the file, you can try something like

```
git log --name-status -- colors.txt
```

and you'll find a commit with `D       colors.txt` which is the commit in which you deleted the file, in my case the short hash is `e1bb165`. You might want to diff against the commit before that

```
git diff colors-test..e1bb165~1 -- colors.txt
```

which gives me

```
green
blue
yellow
-orange
-purple
```

When you pass the `-R` switch to `git diff`, you will get `+` instead of `-` (the inputs are reversed).

Hope that helps.