# Viewing changes to deleted files in git during rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

the question is basicaly the same as [Viewing changes to deleted files in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935712/viewing-changes-to-deleted-files-in-git) but for a rebase rather than a merge.

So :

Let's say that when I branch off from master, there's a file colors.txt on the master branch of my repo with these contents:

```
red
green
blue
yellow
```

I then branch off into my-branch, in which I make the following changes:

1. Delete `colors.txt`
2. Add `red.txt` with these contents:

```
red
```

3. Add `green.txt` with these contents:

```
green
```

4. Add `blue.txt` with these contents:

```
blue
```

5. Add `yellow.txt` with these contents:

```
yellow
```

Now, I know some other guy have been doing modification in this file on master, so before going further I decided to rebase onto master. The file `colors.txt` has been modified to:

```
red
green
blue
yellow
orange
purple
```

During my rebase, the only information I get is that I deleted the file colors.txt

```
deleted by them: colors.txt
```

*the fact that the message is deleted by them is already confusing, but that's not the question*

**So how can I see the changes that have been made to the file on master so I can appropriately resolve the conflict (in this case, by adding the files orange.txt and purple.txt)?**

*I can't use the solution of the linked question because they are merge specific.*

Comment: You make things to complected. When you do a marge, conflicted files are shown in form showing changes in current branch and branch which is merged. If you are intimidated by `>>>>>>>` `<<<<<<<` in conflicted file, there are tools which visualize this quite nicely. I'm using: `kdiff3` (free) and `Beyond Compare` (commercial, but my favorite).

Comment: I think you don't read correctly the question, or I have not express correctly my issue. I have no problem with conflict resolution, and I am not talking about merging. You can redo the step I've describe in the question if you want to see my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I came up with an alias:

```
[alias]
deleted-diff = "!git diff \"$1\"..$(git merge-base \"$1\" \"$2\") -- \"$GIT_PREFIX$3\" #"
```

Usage:

```
git deleted-diff $1 $2 $3
```

`$1` is the branch on top we are rebasing

`$2` is the branch actually rebased

`$3` is the name of the file

for your records:

the `\"` are used to be procted from dangerous file name or space into them

`$GIT_PREFIX` allow the use of relative name for the file

Comment: `git diff a...b -- x` does same thing (note three dots). So this alias gives nothing but name.

Comment: the ... did not work during a rebase because b is on top of a. So there is not diff to show. This is why I specify that this solution is merge specific.